# Keep JVM running on iseries

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-midrange

We are calling a Java program on a iseries machine and the first call to the program is quiet slow. The following calls are fast but if we wait a certain time the call is slow again.

How can I keep the JVM up and running or is there another way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How did you determine it was a "keep the JVM up and running" problem rather than memory pool usage or other problem?

Answer (score 2):

The newest JVM's (IBM Technology for Java) are the fastest available.  The typical problem is that if the JVM's own jars are cached in memory then it is quite fast to load - if not, they need to be loaded from disk as needed which is quite slow.  (There is actually an accelleration process for this under Windows).

You could consider having a small script which simply reads through all the jars for the JVM every X seconds, or to implement a "communicate with daemon JVM through dataqueues" which is the traditional approach for this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you please give an example of such a script or point me to some documentation on how to do that and how to implement the dataqueues?

Comment: Your best bet for now is to have the JVM's run in their own subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider making your java application a server that is running all the time ... your native app can send & receive requests to the server using tcp or data queues.

That way the start up cost for the server is a one time thing and none of the users never have to suffer through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Allocate more memory to the subsystem the JVM is running in.**

Do not call a static method because by definition a static class doesn't have to stay in memory.

Do call methods with *this.

Good Luck

Comment: Implicit is something totally different from static.  Don't call static java classes because by definition they will be loaded and unloaded for each call.  It's the same as calling a rpg that returns with *lr on.  Not a good practice when the issue is speed or in your case how fast it loads ie speed.

Comment: In an IBM i context "calling a program" can be several things depending on context.  For instance by invoking RUNJVA (which is what I am most familiar with) or through an RPG program (which I believe is what you may be talking about).  Semantics appear to be different.  Clarification from OP may be needed.  (and I am glad you edited "dude" into something different)